# Error al implementar Proyecto Xamarin Visual Studio

Tags: java, c#, visual-studio, xamarin

Tengo un detalle al querer ejecutar un proyecto de Xamarin en Visual Studio Community 2019, en el cual me sale el siguiente mensaje:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya probé con varias alternativas:

- Reinstalar Visual Studio
- Reinstalar Xamarin
- Habilitar la opción MultiDex en el proyecto Android.
- Borrar las carpetas /bin y /obj del proyecto y recompilar.
- Agregar un fragmento de línea al archivo AndroidManifest.

  **android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication**

Pero ni aún así se soluciona el detalle que presento.
Alguien que tenga idea de como poder resolver el detalle.